# How can I set the clock of my smart watch using my Windows 10 computer?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, smart-watches

I bought a smart watch (**MS1020**). I would like to set the date and time but I do not have a smartphone or an android device on which to install the associated app ([Yoho Sport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uthink.ring&hl=fr)). **Is there a way to set the clock of my smart watch using my Windows 10 computer?** I was able to pair the watch with my laptop.

---

Here is what I tried so far:

**1. Using an emulator.**
I installed [Nox](https://en.bignox.com/) and used it to install the Yoho Sport app on my virtual Android. However I later read [on this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application) that android emulators do not have bluetooth capabilities so... That was the end of that!

**2. Using pygatt.**
I installed pygatt, but I suspect that I need a USB adapter to use the Bluegiga backend. [I posted a question about his on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546050/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-a-ble-device-with-pygatt-without-using-a-usb-adapte).

**3. Using Windows BLE explorer.**
I installed [Windows BLE explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-le-explorer/9n0ztkf1qd98?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). I was able to connect to my device (see screenshot below) but I do not know how to identify the service associated with clock synchronization and how to access it.

[image]

**4. [EDIT] Using VirtualBox to emulate Android.**
This was suggested by SeanJ (see answers below).
I was able to install a 64 bits Android on my computer using VirtualBox following SeanJ's instructions.
Unfortunately, I ran into two issues.

1. I could not get the Bluetooth to turn on:
   [image]
2. When trying to download YoHo Sports from Google Play I got a message telling me this app was not compatible with my device:
   [image]

At this stage I think that buying a smartphone or borrowing one from a friend is my best option...

Comment: You know you can find a decent Android smartphone for like $10 and use it on wifi only for free.

Answer (score 2):

Use VirtualBox, you can install android and it supports bluetooth.

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product
>   for enterprise as well as home use.

There's a pretty good guide here: https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

Depending on whether your bluetooth module is integrated or plugged in, there are different steps to ensure operation but it seems a well worn path;

e.g. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=83325

Comment: Thanks for your reply, SeanJ. I will let you know if I can manage to connect to my device through a virtual Android using VirtualBox.

Comment: I installed Android on my VirtualBox but unfortunately could not get the app to run on my virtual device (see edited question). Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: @Sheldon that's pretty unspecific, would the app just not run or was it a Bluetooth problem again?

Comment: Both! As detailed in the edited question, I could not turn the Bluetooth on and when trying to install the app, I got a message stating that my device was not compatible with that version of the app. I think that I should first test the app using a smartphone or tablet, in order to confirm which version of android it runs on.

Comment: Nox looks similar to andyroid, basically proprietary emulators you do not have full access.  Vitualbox is different in that you can specify hardware etc and have full access as you would on the device.  It should work...

Answer (score 1):

On the hope that they have used the existing GATT standards for current time services then you might want to have a look at this spec [document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.current_time.xml)

If they have just made up their own service then your only choice is to try and reverse engineer it. Tools like  the ubertooth board may help, but you would need a phone to run the app so you can try and snoop on it. Or to try and decompile the app

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, hardlib! I checked the spec doc that you shared but could not relate the number assigned to the current time service (hexdecimal: 0x1805 / decimal: 6149) to any of the characteristic or service names returned by the Windows BLE Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, none of the uuids you've posted match up, but with a bit more digging you might find something that looks closer

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you were looking for but you can borrow a friends phone if setting the date and time just one time thing. Make them install the app, connect to your watch , then make them uninstall the app and forget your device from the bluetooth list.

Comment: Thanks atayenel, this will be my last resort. But beyond merely synchronizing the watch, I wanted to train myself with GATT, services and characteristics!